# How to build this source code? - missing dependency

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

I need a help how to build this example:
http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/resource/totd154.zip
from this tutorial
http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_154_dynamic_osgi_services

I installed Netbeans 7.1. When I click Clean and Build this error occurs:

```
Failed to execute goal on project helloworld-cdiclient: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.samples.osgi.helloworld:helloworld-cdiclient:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.glassfish:osgi-cdi-api:jar:3.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
  mvn <goals> -rf :helloworld-cdiclient
```

I suppose that I need to add a specific glassfish repository to the maven configuration. Which repository I need?

Comment: to answer your question, http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish should help

Comment: How I can add this repository to the maven configuration?

Comment: `<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>glassfish-repo</id>
            <name>The Glassfish repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/</url>
        </repository>`

Comment: I added this xml configuration into the parent POM file. It works! Thank you!

Comment: @alf: Why don't you add that as an answer so user1103606 can accept it.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann done, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting my comments (sorry I though it will give chance to someone else to answer properly and not on the run):

To answer your question, download.java.net/maven/glassfish should help. The configuration lines are,

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>glassfish-repo</id>
        <name>The Glassfish repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- all the rest... -->
</repositories>
```

Have fun!